# cfquery stuck and does not finish running

Tags: coldfusion

I've been trying to run a dynamic query inside a cfquery tag.  Previously it was running fine.
So now, I can see the debugger enter the cfquery tag, but it does not finish running.  It didn't seem to have made an affect to the database, since nothing was added for that insert query.  Putting try & catch blocks didn't catch anything.

When I looked at the Server Monitor, under Statistics ->Database -> Active Queries -> and sure enough it is listed as an active query.

My other cfqueries tags are running fine though.

There is no problem on the database side.

I've tried changing the content of the tag to run a non dynamic insert query, but it results in the same thing.  When I've changed the content of the query to a badly formed sql, it does catch the error.

Would you suspect this to be a ColdFusion problem?

Comment: please post the query. What is this server monitor you are referring to? I would try to use some more direct way to see wat is going on on the db serverr, like SHOW PROCESSLIST on MySQL

Comment: Turns out there is no problem with the query.  I just had to reboot my computer to get it running again.  Mysterious! :(

Comment: In terms of the server monitor, I was talking about the one that comes with ColdFusion, not the database.

Answer (score 1):

Post your query.  There is going to be something horribly wrong with it.  My gut instinct says deadlock or cross join.